# Cancelling clonezilla disk to disk

Tags: migration, clonezilla, data-migration

I am currently doing clonezilla disk to disk operation because i upgraded my hdd from 500gB(full) to 1TB. But it's taking too long so i consider to just fresh install my laptop.

My question:

- Can i cancel clonezilla disk to disk migration during operation?
- Is it safe to do so?
- Will the data broke or corrupted?

I don't care if the system broke or anything as long my data is fine. Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: How much (in GB) of the stuff on the old HDD would you copy to the new HDD after reinstalling Windows and whatnot?

Comment: Probably 300-400G, i haven't sorted it out yet but it's just some movie/video that i want to copy. EDIT: probably less than 300GB, because i will use the old hdd as storage too.

Comment: In that case aborting is probably not a good idea, because you’ll have to move the data anyway at some time. // Are you currently using some sort of USB enclosure or are both HDDs installed internally?

Comment: Not really an enclosure, but yeah something like that. When i previously tried to copy ~100gB file it only took ~30min or so, so i think it would be faster. How long does it usually take for clonezilla to do this? It's already 3hours, and because there is no progress bar i don't really know the progress.

Comment: If USB 2.0 is involved, copying 500 GB will take at least 4h 45min.

Comment: It's usb 3.0 so it'll be faster. Anyway the  operation still not done yet, how long does it takes usually? Maybe it's the lack of progress bar that make me more impatient.

Comment: So about the initial question can i do it or not? Because i want to abort the operation if it is not done by morning.

Comment: Nvm this, i'm stupid after the first confirmation the keyboard register key press continuously (i think hardware problem) and i thought it is progressing. After i confirm the other confirmation question the process run normally and fast, it's already 30% in the last 15mins. If the source have bad sector and run the recovery option, is it a good idea to clone it? I'm not really knowledgeable in hdd technicality, if the process transfer by sectors will the bad sectors got transferred?